# why does CPU graph inside k8s pod seems consistent and doesn't spike?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, stress-testing

I am running `Stress --cpu` with `--timeout 10` in a loop . Running in an ubuntu image inside a k8s pod through Prometheus then Grafana.

The graph seems consistent as oppose to running the same test on my local machine where you can clearly see the CPU spikes.

Why is that? is it the Minikube balancing it out or rather K8s?

[image: clearly there are no spikes]

Comment: your metrics are most likely aggregated over a minute or more.

Comment: in addition to what @ThomasJungblut said prometheus has a scrape_interval so it is possible that metrics are only scraped during peaks and not within the timeout interval